# Isotope filter load page with filter selected

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I am looking to get Isotope to load with a filter selected on page load. Is this possible? I have the code working well to filter my results based on clicking on a range of  links, but want to make sure that only the results with the class "InitialLoad" included are displayed when the page loads... Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

OK, sorted ;) filter: '.InitialLoad'

Answer (score 0):

sure, that should be possible:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {

  // expecting your isotope container has the id "isotope-container"
  var $grid = $('#isotope-container').isotope();
  var options = ".your-filter-values": 
  $grid.isotope({ filter: options });

}
```